# eslint-plugin-import doesn't work for pathGroup

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint

I'm trying to sort import line with ESLint-plugin-import.
It usually works as I thougth, but it isn't sorted by pathGroups.

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: { browser: true, es2020: true },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:react-hooks/recommended',
    'plugin:import/recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
],
  ignorePatterns: ['dist', '.eslintrc.cjs'],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  plugins: ['react-refresh', 'prettier', 'import'],
  rules: {
    'semi': ['error', 'always'],
    'prettier/prettier': ['error'],
    // Add specific import rules
    'import/order': ['error', {
      'groups': [['builtin', 'external'], 'internal', 'parent', 'sibling', 'index'],
      'pathGroups': [
        {
          'pattern': 'react*',
          'group': 'external',
          'position': 'before'
        },
        {
          'pattern': 'src/contexts/**',
          'group': 'internal',
          'position': 'after'
        },
        {
          'pattern': 'src/styles/**',
          'group': 'internal',
          'position': 'after'
        },
        ...
      ],
      'pathGroupsExcludedImportTypes': ['builtin', 'external'],
      'newlines-between': 'always',
      'alphabetize': { 'order': 'asc', 'caseInsensitive': true },
    }],

    'import/no-duplicates': 'error',
  },
}
```

This is configuration of eslint.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import styled from 'styled-components';

import addPost from '../../assets/Images/Profile/add-post.png';
import defaultProfile from '../../assets/Images/Profile/default-profile.svg';
import menu from '../../assets/Images/Profile/menu.png';
import AddPostModal from '../../components/Profile/AddPostModal.tsx';
import MenuModal from '../../components/Profile/MenuModal.tsx';
import ToggleBar from '../../components/Profile/ToggleBar.tsx';
import Icon from '../../shared/Icon.tsx';
```

And this is a result after applying eslint.
I want to serparate codes by it's directory.